# Error React Hook "useParams" is called in function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Hola tengo un problema recurrente con los Hooks de React. En este caso es con el useParamas de React-Route-dom v6.

Tengo el componente app donde estan las rutas declaradas y debo enviar un parametro a un componente. El componente la recibe y hasta renderiza el parametro pero cuando inicio la aplicación me sale ese cartel en toda la pantalla con el siguiente texto:

**src\components\categSearch.jsx
Line 4:21:  React Hook "useParams" is called in function "categSearch" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks**

Si cierro ese mensaje y utilizo lo que desarrolle, todo anda bien, pero tuve este problema con otros hooks y me gustaria como solucionarlo. Seria poco atractivo que el cliente vea esa pantalla de error cada vez que inicia la pagina.

**Codigo de la ruta**

```
<Routes>
   <Route path="/search/:photo" element={<CategSearch handleLike={handleLike}/>} />
</Routes>
```

**Codigo del componente CateSearch**

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

const categSearch = () => {
    const {photo} = useParams()
    console.log(photo)
  return (
    <div>
        {photo}
    </div>
  )
}

export default categSearch
```

La verdad que no entiendo porque sucede esto. En mi componente de navbar hago uso del Link y no tuve problemas.

Comment: Parece que el problema esta en el nombre del componente `categSearch`, debería iniciar con mayúscula `CategSearch`.

Comment: Hola, lo acabo de probar y funciona. Lo que pensaba era que "si mi componente navbar tiene la n en miniscula y no tiene problemas con Like, porque si tendria problemas el useParams en categSearch". Pues la repuesta es que Like no es un hook jaja. Muchas gracias.